# Using infinite scroll with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, infinite-scroll

I am creating a REST API using Django Rest Framework. The API will serve large amount of data and I want to use infinite scrolling on the page. I would like to use Angular for the frontend. I am not sure how to serve the data such that not all data has to be sent once but only when the user scrolls down.

I am using serializer class -

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('company_name', 'location', 'founded_year')
```

I am not sure about how to implement this. Should i use Django Endless Pagination or could it be done by using the pagination provided by django-rest-framework. I am also not sure about how the frontend of this would work. Web development newbie here, please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a ListAPIView subclass

```
from rest_framework import pagination, generics

class CompanyPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 20  # the no. of company objects you want to send in one go

# Assume url for this view is /api/v1/companies/
class CompanyListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    pagination_class = CompanyPagination
```

Once this is done, you can get first 20 by calling the http://your_domain.com/api/v1/companies/?page=1, `?page=2` will give 21st company to 40th company and so on. (Not specifying `?page=` is like doing `?page=1`)

On your `AngularJS` side, you will maintain some variable which will hold which page number to fetch next. Now you can bind your API request to either click event on some **Load More** type of button, or may be you can detect whether user has scrolled to the bottom, and then do the API request and fetch next set of `Company` objects.

**Note:**

It is not compulsory to use `PageNumberPagination`, you can even use `LimitOffsetPagination` or `CursorPagination` to achieve your objective. Read more about various pagination styles [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

Comment: Is there a way to nullify offset when a queryset ended? Or other way to extend queryset so it doesn't end?

Answer (score 2):

You should give [CursorPagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#cursorpagination) a try.
I don't know exactly whether it's infinite or not but it's definitively for huge sets.